# VB.NET Listening Server is using max CPU

Tags: .net, vb.net, frameworks, cpu

I'm busy with a server -> client -> server software, the client connects to the server and asking for a string, the server responds it back.

However, when multiple connections are made, like 4, the CPU of my computer is raised to 100%

Here is my code.

```
Imports System.Net ' for IPAddress
Imports System.Net.Sockets 'for TcpListener
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
Dim servePort As Integer = 28960
Dim requestCount As Integer
Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
Dim dataFromClient As String
Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
Dim serverResponse As String
Dim rCount As String
Sub Main()
    Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(servePort)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim counter As Integer
    Console.Title = ("Server")
    msg("Starting Server...")
    serverSocket.Start()
    msg("Server started on port " & servePort)
    msg("")
    counter = 0

    While (True)
        counter += 1
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
        If clientSocket.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString = "127.0.0.1:28961" Then
            clientSocket.Close()
            Exit While
        End If

        msg("Client " + clientSocket.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString + " connected.")
        Dim client As New handleClinet
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = _
                        clientSocket.GetStream()
        client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter))

    End While

    clientSocket.Close()
    serverSocket.Stop()

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
    mesg.Trim()
    Console.WriteLine(mesg)
End Sub

Public Class handleClinet
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim clNo As String
    Public Sub startClient(ByVal inClientSocket As TcpClient, _
    ByVal clineNo As String)
        Me.clientSocket = inClientSocket
        Me.clNo = clineNo
        Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
        ctThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub doChat()
        requestCount = 0

        While (True)
            Try
                requestCount = requestCount + 1
                Dim ip As String = clientSocket.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString
                Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = _
                        clientSocket.GetStream()
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
                dataFromClient = _
                dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
                msg("<< " & dataFromClient)
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)

                If dataFromClient.ToLower = "hydra_ver" Then
                    serverResponse = "0.94"
                Else
                   serverResponse = "Unknown Command"
                End If


                Else
                    serverResponse = "Unknown Command"
                End If
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                networkStream.Flush()
                msg(">> " & serverResponse)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End While

    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow.

You're opening and closing connections in a forever loop?

Make a socket listener, then handle stream events.  This is c# but i'm sure you've gotten used to back-dating to VBNet by now.

```
public void portSocketListener() 
{
    Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPAddress hostIP = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(hostIP, 28961);
    listenSocket.Bind(ep);
    listenSocket.Listen(1);
}
```